# CSS body height not behaving in Firefox?

Tags: css

Basically i have a div on my main page that contains the content, now when the content goes over the bottom of the page so the user has to scroll down to view the lower half of the content everything works as it should.

That is with body `{ height:auto; }`, however when this div only has content that can be viewed without scrolling there is a problem with body `{ -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px #33333; }` meaning that the shadow comes half way up the page.

It is hard to explain so just have a look for your self:

> http://middle.dyndns-server.com/index.html
>   This page has the content extending the dive so height:auto works

and

> http://middle.dyndns-server.com/schedule.html
>   This page does not have the content so the inner shadow doesn't work properly in firefox. I can correct this with `height:100%` but then the same happens to the index.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add doctype first

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

**css**

```
html,body{
  min-height:100%;
}

    #page{
       min-height:100%;
    }
```

Checkout the below links:

http://balam.in/personal/stackoverflow/schedule.html

http://balam.in/personal/stackoverflow/index.html

You need to put the style declaration inside head tag or in the attached external stylesheet

```
<style>
html,#page,body{

min-height:100%;

}
</style>
```

Comment: Should the CSS be put at the start as a reset or integrated in?

I used it as a reset but it hasn't solved the problem : (

Thanks a lot.

Comment: hell yeah. this finally solved my longterm firefox issue. thanks alot for this hint mate!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a rule to the #page declaration: `#page{min-height:100%;}`
And one to the Body delcaration: `body{height:100%;}`

Comment: I have done that and if you look at the links it hasn't worked, or i have implemented it wrong?

Thanks